# Adding data to a txt file (and saving it there)

Tags: python, file, parameters

I am a complete beginner with programming. I try to add some information to a txt file, but it doesn't work... It does print the parameters, but won't add it in the txt file. All the help will be appreciated.

```
def addpersons(student_number, name, phone_number):

new_person = student_number + name + phone_number
data = data + new_person

with open("data.txt", 'w') as f:
  f.write (data)

print(200300, "Jim", "031213245123")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please copy code into your question and [format it as code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting); don't post it as a screenshot because it makes it impossible for people to copy/paste your code and try it for themselves.

Comment: You didn't actual call the funtion. Try `addpersons(1, "a", "1")`

Comment: You are trying to write `data` to a file and never pass `data` to your function. Your IDE is telling you look at the underlined code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that all the code you have? Because you are adding data + person where `data` is not defined, that should throw an error. Which you probably don't see because if that is all your Code you are not calling the function add all.

To have it work make sure you acctually call the function `addperson`and make sure that data is defined before you do `data = data + person`

Also there shouldn't be a space between `f.write` and `(data)` but I doubt that matters.

Here is a version that should work:

```
def addpersons(student_number, name, phone_number):
    new_person = str(student_number) + name + phone_number

    with open("data.txt", 'w') as f:
        f.write(new_person)

addpersons(200300, "Jim", "031213245123")
print(200300, "Jim", "031213245123")
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your code and lets just say its completely wrong. Also in future please use the md feature with backticks to simply paste your code, it makes life much easier for people who try and answer, anyways i digress. Your first mistake is in this line
`new_person = student_number + name + phone_number`
Student_number is an integer, you cannot concat ints and strs in python, you can use the `str()` builtin to convert it to a string.
Your next error is:
`data = data + new_person`
data is not defined before this, i assume you are doing this so you can put multiple people in, however you can achieve this by appending to the file instead of writing. This is achievable by doing:
`with open("data.txt", "a") as f:`
Then you can just do:

```
with open("data.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(new_student)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reaction! I'm on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def addpersons(student_number, name, phone_number):

    data = ""
    new_person = str(student_number) + name + str(phone_number)
    data = data + new_person
    
    with open("data.txt", 'a') as f:
        f.write(data + '\n')

addpersons(200300, "Jim", "03121324")
addpersons(12345, "Jorj", "098765434")
```

Output:

[image]

or Try this:

```
def addpersons(student_number, name, phone_number):

    data = ""
    new_person = str(student_number) + "\t" + name + "\t" + str(phone_number)
    data = data + new_person
    
    with open("data.txt", 'a') as f:
        f.write(data + '\n')

addpersons(200300, "Jim", "03121324")
addpersons(12345, "Jorj", "098765434")
```

Output:

[image]